# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here are the updated codes with traceback

Here is the model:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="(app_label)s_%(class)s_creator")
    edited_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="(app_label)s_%(class)s_editor")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     
    class Meta:
            abstract = True
 
class Department(Base):
    dept_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

> Error Traceback:
> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\shell.pyc in ()
> ----> 1 test = Department.objects.create(name='test',description='test')

```
C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.pyc in get_prep_value(se
lf, value)
553 if value is None:
554 return None
--> 555 return int(value)
556
557 def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<property object at 0x000000000332AB38>'
```

Comment: You need to fix the messed-up indentation of your code. It's not optional in Python!

Comment: Also, the code you posted doesn't call `int()` at all. Which line is triggering the error? Please post the entire traceback.

Comment: when saving it test.save()

Answer (score 1):

You must supply a `user` when you create  a department. You can access the current user as `request.user` if you are in a view

```
user = request.user
```

or fetch any user from the database if you are testing in the shell

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1) # get
```

then create the `department`:

```
department = Department(name='test',
                        description='test',
                        user=user,
                        )
```

Finally, your `default=User.pk` is incorrect. For a user instance you can access `user.pk`, but the class attribute `User.pk` is not pk of the current user as you might think it is.

Comment: It doesn't look as if you have made either of the changes I suggested to you. 1. You must specify a user when creating a department. 2. You must remove `default=User.pk` from your `Department.user` field because it doesn't make any sense.